# DbContext Scaffold referenced assembly error

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Trying to create database scaffolding with EntityFrameworkCore 1.1.0 using the

> Scaffold-DbContext "{ Your DB connect string }"
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models

nuget console command but I'm getting

> Error: assembly specified in the dependencies manifest was not found
>   -- package: 'BO', version: '1.0.0', path: 'BO.dll'

error.

Both my DAL and BO layer class libraries are .NET Core class libraries and I'm getting this error even when I remove the reference to BO class library from my DAL layer.

BO.dll is actually located in ..\DAL\bin\Debug\netstandard1.6 but I get the same error where ever I copy the file to.

Here is my DAL project.json file:

```
{
    "version": "1.0.0-*",

    "dependencies": {
        "BO": "1.0.0-*",
        "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.1.0",
        "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design": "1.1.0",
        "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational": "1.1.0",
        "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational.Design": "1.1.0",
        "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.1.0",
        "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Design": "1.1.0",
        "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.1.0-preview4-final",
        "NETStandard.Library": "1.6.1"
    },

    "frameworks": {
        "netstandard1.6": {
            "imports": "dnxcore50"
        }
    }
}
```

Anyone else run into this or any ideas how to resolve this issue?

Comment: What is BO?....

Comment: It's a .NET Core class library as mentioned in the question.